# Running PHP from command line windows

Tags: php, dll

**I have previously installed servers**  like xampp and appserv but I uninstalled those for some reasons.
and now I want to use php from command line and after I set the path in 
`Environment Variables` . and changed the `php.ini`  as some previous answers mentioned it didn't resolve my problem.

I'm guessing that **appserv** has tampered with some files  thus I installed the latest version of **PHP** Hoping that those libraries will exist but got the same error

 and this is the error I get when typing `php -v`  in command line:

---

> php -v PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_dbase.dll' (tried: C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_dbase.dll (The
>   specified module could not be found.),
>   C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_php_dbase.dll.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
>   to load dynamic library 'php_gd2.dll' (tried:
>   C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.), C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_php_gd2.dll.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mbstring.dll' (tried:
>   C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not
>   be found.), C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_php_mbstring.dll.dll (The
>   specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.dll'
>   (tried: C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_mysql.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.), C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll (The
>   specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli.dll'
>   (tried: C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.), C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_php_mysqli.dll.dll (The
>   specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_sockets.dll' (tried: C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_sockets.dll (The
>   specified module could not be found.),
>   C:/AppServ\php5\ext\php_php_sockets.dll.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer
>   available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Try a `php --ini` and check where your php is loading its `php.ini` from. Sounds like you have something in your PATH pointing to an old php folder

Comment: can't run that too , same error pops up.
are there any other methods to know where is it loading  php.ini @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok, so go through your PATH and remove any reference to any other PHP folder

Comment: did so , there weren't any references to other php folders just the one I created.

Comment: Did you check that the `extension_dir` in `php.ini` is pointing to the `ext` folder

Comment: changed the php.ini-development   to 

 extension_dir = "C:\php" @RiggsFolly

Comment: Try `extension_dir = "C:/php/ext/" `

Comment: Sorry refresh the page, had finger trouble on that comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
the problem is still there